# Question about efficient arguments mapping

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, refactoring

The code below made it easier for me to use Pymongo.

But I'm trying to refactoring it because I think it's too inefficient.

Since I'm a beginner, I've tried a few times, but I'm not satisfied with it, so I'd like some advice.

I'm sorry the code is messy. Just refer to it,

and please let me know if any libraries or a simple example.Thank you!

```
def find_(self, collection, find_value=None, projection=None, sort=None, skip=None, limit=None, multi_array=None, cursor=False):
    if sort is None:
       if skip is None and limit is None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection)
       if skip is not None and limit is None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).skip(skip)
       if skip is None and limit is not None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).limit(limit)
       if skip is not None and limit is not None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).skip(skip).limit(limit)
    else:
       arg = tuple((key, val) for key, val in sort.items())
       if skip is None and limit is None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).sort(arg)
       if skip is not None and limit is None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).sort(arg).skip(skip)
       if skip is None and limit is not None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).sort(arg).limit(limit)
       if skip is not None and limit is not None:
           cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection).sort(arg).skip(skip).limit(limit)
```

Comment: `find_value if projection is None else find_value` is *always* `find_value`; is there a typo there?

Comment: I would consider it very unlikely that this is the source of any performance problems you may be having. Readability? Maintainability? Probably some room for improvement there. But performance wise? Any improvements you could make to this would be on the micro level. With optimization for speed, the general rule is that if you don't double the speed, you've accomplished nothing. You probably won't be able to double the speed here.

Comment: find_value if projection is None else find_value, projection -> retuns (find_value) or (find_value, projection) thank you

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It's convenient for me to use the code. But the code I made seemed so bad that I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is about as efficient as it's going to get, as `cursor_result` is always set by exactly one branch in which all the real work is done. The only problem is that it has a *lot* of duplicated code. You can factor it out by handling each option one at a time.

```
def find_(self, collection, find_value=None, projection=None, sort=None, skip=None, limit=None, multi_array=None, cursor=False):
    # Get the right path and call find
    cursor_result = self.db_path[collection].find(find_value, projection)

    # Sort if necessary
    if sort is not None:
        cursor_result = cursor_result.sort(tuple(sort.items()))

    # Skip if necessary
    if skip is not None:
        cursor_result = cursor_result.skip(skip)

    # Limit if necessary
    if limit is not None:
        cursor_result = cursor_result.limit(limit)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!. It's easy to see and it works. I wouldn't have thought about it on my own. It would be great to have someone like you next to me. Thank you.